# Google Maps API doesn't load the right centerposition, instead loads in the area of the last added marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

The Google Maps API doesn't load the centerposition which is defined in the initialize() function, instead it loads an unknown position around the last added marker (marker6).

What's causing it to not load the right position?

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB22617JOlm8uh6JVe-cuT3mOlyXd_Vb7o&sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var map;
    
        $(document).ready(function() {
                                   
                               
        initialize();
        
        var BW = new google.maps.LatLng(50.892726, 3.471283);
        map.panTo(BW);
    
        $("#test1").click(function() {
        var BW = new google.maps.LatLng(50.892726, 3.471283);
        map.panTo(BW);
        resetLink();
        $('#test1').css ({'color':'white'});
        });
        
        $("#test2").click(function() {
        var BW2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.863026,3.442379);
        map.panTo(BW2);
        resetLink();
        $('#test2').css ({'color':'white'});
        });
        
        $("#test3").click(function() {
        var BW3 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.748454,3.131254);
        map.panTo(BW3);
        resetLink();
        $('#test3').css ({'color':'white'});
        });
        
        $("#test4").click(function() {
        var BW4 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.272504,16.220863);
        map.panTo(BW4);
        resetLink();
        $('#test4').css ({'color':'white'});
        });
        
        $("#test5").click(function() {
        var BW5 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.498496,5.397516);
        map.panTo(BW5);
        resetLink();
        $('#test5').css ({'color':'white'});
        });
        
        $("#test6").click(function() {
        var BW6 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.35057,16.523513);
        map.panTo(BW6);
        resetLink();
        $('#test6').css ({'color':'white'});
        });
        
        
    });
        

    function resetLink() {
        $('#test1').css ({'color':'#7faacb'});
        $('#test2').css ({'color':'#7faacb'});
        $('#test3').css ({'color':'#7faacb'});
        $('#test4').css ({'color':'#7faacb'});
        $('#test5').css ({'color':'#7faacb'});
        $('#test6').css ({'color':'#7faacb'});
    }
    

    
    function initialize() {
         var mapOptions = {
          scrollwheel: false,
          scaleControl: false,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.89266,3.47237),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

       map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
        

      
        
      var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<p><b>Building Plastics nv</b><br />' +
      'Herlegemstraat 14<br />'+
      'B-9771 Nokere<br />'+
      '056 60 48 11'+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>';
      
      var contentString2 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<p><b>Building Windows</b><br />' +
      'Grote Leiestraat 205<br />'+
      'B-8570 Anzegem<br />'+
      '056 62 11 40 '+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>';
      
      var contentString3 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<p><b>Building Plastics France</b><br />' +
      'Avenue Europe 46<br />'+
      'F-59435 Roncq Cedex<br />'+
      '03 20 03 99 99 '+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>';
          
      var contentString4 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<p><b>Building Plastics CZ</b><br />' +
      'Velk&agrave; B&iacute;te&#353; 76<br />'+
      '595 01 Velk&agrave; B&iacute;te&#353;<br />'+
      '800 400 115'+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>';
      
      var contentString5 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<p><b>Building Plastics NL</b><br />' +
      'Magazijnweg 23<br />'+
      '5683 CV Best<br />'+
      '0499 37 53 27'+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>';
      
     var contentString6 = '<div id="content">'+
      '<p><b>Building Plastics PL</b><br />' +
      'Przemyslowa 3<br />'+
      '64-320 Buk<br />'+
      '061 814 91 61'+
      '</p>'+
      '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
       maxWidth: 250,

    });
  
    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString2,
       maxWidth: 250,

    });
    var infowindow3 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString3,
       maxWidth: 250,

    });
       var infowindow4 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString4,
       maxWidth: 250,

    });
       var infowindow5 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString5,
       maxWidth: 250,

    });
      var infowindow6 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString6,
       maxWidth: 250,

    });
       
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8923380,3.477300);
        var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.862987,3.446863);
        var myLatlng3 = new google.maps.LatLng(50.748411,3.136749);
        var myLatlng4 = new google.maps.LatLng(49.271619,16.225359);
        var myLatlng5 = new google.maps.LatLng(51.498349,5.401329);
        var myLatlng6 = new google.maps.LatLng(52.350542,16.52786);
       

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'BP1'
    });
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng2,
      map: map,
      title: 'BP2'
    });
    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng3,
      map: map,
      title: 'BP3'
    });
    var marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng4,
      map: map,
      title: 'BP4'
    });
      var marker5 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng5,
      map: map,
      title: 'BP5'
    });
      var marker6 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng6,
      map: map,
      title: 'BP6'
    });
      
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
         });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
        infowindow2.open(map,marker2);
         });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
        infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
         });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', function() {
        infowindow4.open(map,marker4);
         });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker5, 'click', function() {
        infowindow5.open(map,marker5);
         });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker6, 'click', function() {
        infowindow6.open(map,marker6);
        });
        
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        infowindow2.open(map,marker2);
        infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
        infowindow4.open(map,marker4);
        infowindow5.open(map,marker5);
        infowindow6.open(map,marker6);
        
          }
          
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i found the problem,

when initialized, it open al 6 textballoons, causing it to bug? idk the exact reason for this?

anyway, i changed

```
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
    infowindow2.open(map,marker2);
    infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
    infowindow4.open(map,marker4);
    infowindow5.open(map,marker5);
    infowindow6.open(map,marker6);
```

to

```
    $("#test2").click(function() {
     infowindow2.open(map,marker2);
    });

    $("#test3").click(function() {
     infowindow3.open(map,marker3);
    });

    $("#test4").click(function() {
     infowindow4.open(map,marker4);
    });

    $("#test5").click(function() {
     infowindow5.open(map,marker5);
    });

    $("#test6").click(function() {
     infowindow6.open(map,marker6);
    });
```

so it only opens the text balloons when clicked and sent to the position.

Can't explain why because I actually don't know javascript that good.

Answer (score 0):

First initialize(); is called and sets the position to:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.89266,3.47237)
```

But right after that you call this:

```
var BW = new google.maps.LatLng(50.892726, 3.471283);
map.panTo(BW);
```

So BW is your new center. Is this what you meant?

Comment: oh, should be the same coordinates (50.892726, 3.471283).
I changed it but the problem remains..

I did a panTo next to the initialize out of desperation..